# Why am I unable to authenticate via Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

Newbie coder having issues authenticating via tweepy. below is the code.

```
import tweepy
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""
api_key=""
api_secret_key=""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("API_KEY","API_SECRET_KEY")
auth.set_access_token("ACCESS_TOKEN","ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

if api.verify_credentials() == False:
    print("The user credentials are invalid.")
else:
    print("The user credentials are valid.")
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly? Is there an error message? An unexpected behavior? Anything else? How are we supposed to help you if we don't know that? By the way, `api.verify_credentials()` returns a tweepy.User object, not a boolean.

Comment: I'm getting this error - TweepError: [{'code': 89, 'message': 'Invalid or expired token.'}]

Comment: the tokens or neither invalid or expired